# Using ordinal numbers for elapsed time

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Иван начал жить в Москве шестого января 2017. Сегодня четвертое апреля 2022. Следовательно

а) Иван живет в Москве пятый год.

б) Иван живет в Москве шестой год.

Which phrase is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`б` is the the correct one.
Or, to express a duration in whole years:

> Иван прожил в Москве 5 лет.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the spirit of the question, the ordinal numbers in such a construct should be interpreted like this:

*It is the sixth year [in progress] now [since the stated event]*, i.e. 5 full years + part of the current year.

Another typical example:

> Маше уже восьмой год пошёл.

Masha is in her 8th year, i.e. she is seven-and-a-bit years old.